# Add condition to angular expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have an angular expression which resolves to a String, can I add a condition to that expression which will append extra text to that String?

I have:

```
<span>{{groupType}}</span>
```

But if `groupType` resolves to car or animal, I want to add an s to the end of the String.

Can I add a condition to the expression to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Ternary operator in Angular expression

```
<span>{{groupType === 'Car' || groupType === 'Animal' ? groupType + 's' : groupType}}</span>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, this works, but you really shouldn't put the logic in the html.

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right but there involves no business logic, just appending `s` to the string, I think is fine

Comment: Unless you need to do the same string manipulation in multiple different locations, of course.

Comment: @Cerbrus In that case a function will be useful, as you've shown. I wont update my answer now as it'll be similar to yours :)

Comment: @Cerbrus since angular allows use of ternary operator in views,it is obvious that certain amount of logic can be implemented inside views.Otherwise there is no point allowing use of ternary operators inside views.

Comment: @Abdul23: _can_, yes. However, just because you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
<span>{{["Car", "Animal"].indexOf(groupType) >= 0 ? groupType + 's' : groupType}}</span>
```

I use an array of names with `indexOf`, because it's a little shorter than *"x or y or z"*

---

Ideally, you don't want this logic in your HTML, though. I'd suggest putting it in a function in your controller:

```
$scope.getGroupType = function(type){
    if(["Car", "Anumal"].indexOf(type) >= 0)
        return type + 's';
    return type;
};
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<span>{{getGroupType(groupType)}}</span>
```